# Can't redirect a subdirectory to a subdomain with nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have listingnaples.com (a Laravel app) and I want to have listingnaples.com/blog/ to have a Wordpress install. I can't just put Wordpress in my /blog/ for security reasons so I am trying to put it in blog.listingnaples.com on my server.

My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name blog.listingnaples.com;
    access_log /srv/www/blog.listingnaples.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/blog.listingnaples.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {
            root /srv/www/blog.listingnaples.com;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

    location ~ \.php$  {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/blog.listingnaples.com/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name listingnaples.com;
    access_log /srv/www/listingnaples.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/listingnaples.com/logs/error.log;

    location /blog {
            proxy_pass  https://blog.listingnaples.com;
    }

    location / {
            root   /srv/www/listingnaples.com/public;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* ^((?!\/blog)(.+)\.php)$  {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/listingnaples.com/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

When I open my browser and visit listingnaples.com/blog/ it gives me the Laravel route 404. I'm able to go to https://blog.listingnaples.com/ and see the Wordpress engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want users to access the WP at listingaples.com/blog, then instead of `proxy_pass` use (inside the `server {}` block that has your app- not the WP as `document_root`)

rewrite ^/blog$ http://blog.listingaples.com redirect;